# Bochner's theorem

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

I'm reading [Bochner's theorem](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matsr/ProbI/Lecture7.pdf). Now I'm having problem with part on the third page: $\int_{s\in [0,T], s+u\in [0, T]} ds=1-\frac{|u|}{T}$? How to deduce it?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is true is that for $|u|\leq T$,
$$
\int_{s\in[0,T],s+u\in[0,T]} \,ds = T - |u|,
$$
and in those lecture notes notice that a factor of $T$ is dropped, which gives you $(1-|u|/T)$.  Moreover we do have $|u|\leq T$ because $u$ is being integrated from $-T$ to $T$.

To do this integral, just observe that when $u>0$,
$$
\{s\in [0,T] \mid s+u\in [0,T]\} = [0,T-u]
$$
and likewise when $u<0$,
$$
\{s\in [0,T] \mid s+u\in [0,T]\} = [u,T].
$$